# How to check if BLOB is null?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How do you check whether the value of a column in an SQLite database is null, when it is of type Blob? I am fetching a Cursor like:

```
public Cursor fetchArticle(int i) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = mDatabase.query(true, "api_content",
        new String[] { "_id", "ArticleName",     "ArticleText","ImageLink", "Image" },
        KEY_ID + "=" + i, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

How can I check if the value of the `Image` column, index 4, is null? I have tried:

- Using [`isNull()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull%28int%29), which always returns false when in fact the value should be null.
- Using `articleCursor.getBlob(4) == null`, where `articleCursor` is a valid Cursor (returns false).

To further complicate matters, when I print `articleCursor.getBlob(4)[0]` it returns values such as `78` or `91`, which do not resemble anything I consider `null`. It is impossible the database has any data in that column; it must be null.

Comment: What does a plain SQL query on the command line return for that column/row?

Comment: Have you tried Querying for 'length(x)' instead of or complementary to 'x'? It will Return Null iff x is Null and no dB driver and/or Client Buffer should be confused by arbitrary octet sequences.

Comment: @DaDaDom a plain query returns NULL.

Comment: @collapsar, when you say 'x', are you referring to the byte array returned by articleCursor.getBlob(4)?

Comment: @alejandro: no, actually i'm referring to the sql statement, or the arguments to the cursor constructor, resp.; instead of selecting a result set column you should be able to specify an sql expression over such a column, namely 'length(Image)' in your example - you best consult the manual  or class api to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

Method getBlob() always has a value. If value of this column is empty or null, when you use method length, the result is 1.

Example:

```
byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
if(image.length == 1) {
   //column data is empty
} else{
   //column has data
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: An empty blob's length() returns 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below method which return that blob is empty or not

```java
private Boolean isBlobEmpty(Blob blob) {
    boolean blobFlag = false;

    try {
        if (blob == null && blob.length() == 0) {
            blobFlag = true;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
        blobFlag = true;
        logger.debug("Error while checking blob : " + e1);
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        blobFlag = true;
        logger.debug("Error while checking blob : " + e2);
    }

    return blobFlag;
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the NPE catching using short hand evalution: `if (blob == null || blob.length() == 0)`. The right-hand side of the `||` will just be executed if the left side was not `true`, therefore the condition matches in both cases without throwing an NPE.

Answer (score -2):

Please find below query to get the value Y or N

```
select id, 
 case
      when myblob is not null then 'Y'
      else 'N'
 end,
 myblob
```

If blob is null then it returns N else Y.